# cell array issue - Matlab

Tags: matlab

Inside a loop I am generating an output (e.g., outputLine) which I wish to accumulate/add to a cell array.

Therefore, I am using this small snippet:

```
for...
    outputLine=strcat(FileName,',',coordString);
    outputTable=vertcat(outputTable,outputLine);
end
```

I get the obvious error as outputTable is not declared and if I add at the beginning of the script `outputTable=' ';`

I get this error “Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.”

How can I accumulate the output in a cell array?

Comment: Try `outputTable={}` before the loop. Also, you can replace `vertcat` with `{;}` e.g. `outputTable={outputTable;outputLine};`

Comment: Thanks. outputTable={} works fine but only with the vertcat.

Comment: To concatenate two cells, [] has to be used, {} creates a nested cell.

Comment: In this case, I would use append : `outTable{end+1}=outputLine `

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the error is that strings are arrays of type `char`. If you want to concatenate strings vertically, they have to be the same length to make up a proper `char` matrix, just like arrays of any other type.

You may want to read the Mathworks pages on [how to index cell arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html) as well as [how to combine cell arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/combine-cell-arrays.html).

There are a few of ways to append to your cell array. First off, the array has to be defined as a cell array. If you know how big it is going to be (which is the preferable case), before the loop, do

```
outputTable = cell(N, 1);
```

Otherwise, you will have to reallocate the array every time

```
outputTable = {}
```

For the case where the size is known,

```
outputTable{i} = outputLine;
```

Here `i` would be the index in the `for` loop or an external counter that you initialize before the loop and increment whenever you make an assignment. This [will also work](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/add-cells-to-a-cell-array.html) if you do not know the size of the list up front, but not as efficiently.

For the case where you just want to append to the list, do

```
outputTable = [outputTable; outputLine]
```

[The notation `[;]` is syntactic sugar](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/redefining-concatenation-for-your-class.html) for [`vertcat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html), which you can use explicitly:

```
outputTable = vertcat(outputTable, outputLine)
```